# Rewrite source IP in TCP replies using iptables

Tags: iptables, routing, nat, rewrite

I'd like to rewrite the source IP on TCP/514 traffic leaving a redhat machine, for connections that weren't initiated from the machine.

The machine receives TCP/514 traffic on an interface, for example 10.10.0.20, and then I'd like to return the traffic as though the reply is from 10.10.0.15 (which isn't assigned to the machine).

If I was initiating the connection, then I could use the nat table, and:

`iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp --sport 514 -j SNAT --to=10.10.0.15`

..but since I'm replying to incoming traffic, I can't make it hit the nat table (as far as I can tell).  Ignoring the reasons *why* I need to do things this way, how can I make this work?

More background:

> It's a redhat 7 machine sitting behind a Netscaler VIP which receives
>   syslog traffic over TCP (not UDP).  I'm using client IP passthrough on
>   the VIP.  Due to the firewall seeing return traffic coming from the
>   syslog server IP, not the VIP's IP, the firewall is dropping the
>   traffic, and hence I'd like to rewrite TCP replies from the syslog
>   server so they come from the VIP's IP address.  Since the traffic
>   doesn't originate from the backend server, I don't seem to be able to
>   use the nat table (and therefore no `-j SNAT`).

What I see now is:

```
13:13:45.439683 IP 10.10.0.8.31854 > 10.10.0.20.514: Flags [S], seq 544116376, win 8190, options [mss 1460], length 0
13:13:45.439743 IP 10.10.0.20.514 > 10.10.0.8.31854: Flags [S.], seq 4163333198, ack 544116377, win 14600, options [mss 1460], length 0
```

What I want to see is:

```
13:13:45.439683 IP 10.10.0.8.31854 > 10.10.0.20.514: Flags [S], seq 544116376, win 8190, options [mss 1460], length 0
13:13:45.439743 IP 10.10.0.15.514 > 10.10.0.8.31854: Flags [S.], seq 4163333198, ack 544116377, win 14600, options [mss 1460], length 0
```

Comment: What topology is your VIP network?  In common configuration the VIP box does DNAT to the syslog server,  i.e. it rewrites destination address of incoming traffic and source address of return traffic.  If you want to perform DSR, the VIP box should forward traffic to the syslog server with packets keeping the VIP address for destination.

Comment: It's does DNAT, but not SNAT, so traffic reaching the syslog server has the new (correct) destination IP of the syslog server (10.10.0.20 in my example) but still has the source IP of the client, rather than the Netscaler's VIP outbound IP. The problem is that the default gateway on the syslog server isn't the Netscaler, so traffic doesn't go back to the Netscaler - it goes direct to the firewall - it's asymmetrically routed. I realise this isn't ideal, but it's a hosted environment and I'm unable to change the topology.

Comment: I should add that the reason I can't use SNAT on the Netscaler is that the syslog server needs the host IP in order to separate traffic by host. We deal with some syslog traffic which has no host information in it, and the only way to get it is from the source IP of the traffic.

Comment: The most efficient way would be to configure Direct Server Return mode correctly on Netscaler, where Netscaler does MAC based forwarding to the syslog server with destination address unchanged (10.10.0.15).  Anyway I post my answer to workaround your DNAT configuration and topology.

Comment: DSR is an option.  I'll experiment with this first, as the VIP's frontend IP sits outside the subnet that the syslog server is in (behind a firewall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### DSR method

The most efficient way would be to configure Direct Server Return mode correctly on Netscaler, where Netscaler does MAC based forwarding to the syslog server with destination VIP address unchanged (10.10.0.15).

The syslog server also needs to have that VIP address in order to receive packets forwarded from Netscaler.  The address can be assigned to any internal interface like `lo` or `dummy0`.

```
ip addr add 10.10.0.15/32 dev lo
```

And you have to set some sysctls on the incoming interface (here I assume `eth0`) to avoid [problems with ARP for VIP](http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.arp_problem.html) (see [6.7. The Cure: 2.6.x kernels - arp_ignore/arp_announce](http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.arp_problem.html#2.6_arp)).  Add the following in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and run `sysctl -p`.

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_announce = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 2
```

Note that it's useless to set `arp_ignore` / `arp_announce` on `lo`.

### DNAT method

If Netscaler does DNAT on the incoming traffic, then the syslog server should definitely forward the return traffic to Netscaler as well so that it could free connection tracking resource.  That's the most natural way to complete address translation.

In this case you might want to utilize the policy routing on the syslog server.  With this you can apply a special routing table to pakcets in the specific condition like "outgoing TCP packets from port 514".

There are HOWTO docs on Linux advanced routing like this.  I recommend you to look through the latter mini HOWTO to understand the following instruction.

- [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control](http://www.lartc.org/)
- [Linux Advanced Routing Mini HOWTO](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/iproute2.html)

First, define the special routing table named `VIP` with any ID in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`:

```
1 VIP
```

Add a default route to VIP (10.10.0.15) to this `VIP` table:

```
ip route add default via 10.10.0.15 table VIP
```

Add an entry to iptables `mangle` table to mark `1` on outgoing TCP packets from port 514:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 514 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Add a rule to look up `VIP` routing table on packets with mark `1`:

```
ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table VIP
```

You can see rules defined so far by `ip rule list`.  Rules are processed in ascending order of priority value (0 is highest precedence).

```
# ip rule list
0:  from all lookup local 
32765:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup VIP 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

You can check the content of each routing table like this:

```
# ip route ls table local
# ip route ls table VIP
# ip route ls table main
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I'm holding off accepting it for now, as the VIP sits outside the subnet that the syslog server is in (and hence behind a firewall, which would drop the traffic).  I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer, but I greatly appreciate the time you took to reply.  I'll upvote as soon as I have enough rep.

Comment: Oh, VIP and the syslog server are in different subnets?  Then neither this policy routhing trick nor DSR is likely to work.  You might well manage to find a way to change the configuration of router/firewall between them...  It would be nice if you could configure the policy routhing above on the router.

Comment: Turns out DSR works a treat.  Are you able to make a new answer with DSR as the recommendation so I can accept it?  I used https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX110501 as a reference for how to reconfigure the VIP, and used https://www.barracuda.com/support/knowledgebase/50160000000GNC9 for loopback configuration.

Comment: Good!  I've updated my answer.  Be careful that [barracuda's instruction](http://www.barracuda.com/kb?id=50160000000GNC9) seems incorrect as they are using obsolete or wrong configuration.

Comment: What I actually wanted to say was that you shouldn't set that sysctl on `lo`.  From [LVS-HOWTO](http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.arp_problem.html#2.6_arp): On the realservers the VIP will still be on lo (as for the hidden method). If the reply packets to the client are routed through eth0, then the arp announcements/requests are made through eth0 and you will apply the arp_ignore/arp_announce sysctls to eth0, not to lo (you cannot use arp_ignore/arp_announce on lo).

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer - I've accepted it.  For future reference: I just used the `ifconfig <interface_name> <ip_address> netmask 255.255.255.255 -arp up` example to test.  I created a new `ifcfg-lo:0` interface config file and used `ONPARENT=yes` instead of `ONBOOT=yes`, as well as `ARP=no`.

Comment: `What I actually wanted to say was that you shouldn't set that sysctl on lo. From LVS-HOWTO: On the realservers the VIP will still be on lo (as for the hidden method). If the reply packets to the client are routed through eth0, then the arp announcements/requests are made through eth0 and you will apply the arp_ignore/arp_announce sysctls to eth0, not to lo (you cannot use arp_ignore/arp_announce on lo)` - Good to know, I'll leave the sysctl portion out of my config.

Comment: As a secondary question: does the arp_ignore / arp_announce flags prevent eth0 from ARPing for the primary IP of the server?  I still need the main interface to function as per normal (ie, reply to requests for 10.10.0.20), since other traffic reaches this server besides syslog.  Can't move to chat because I don't have enough rep yet.. :/

Comment: From my understanding it doesn't interfere with other traffic on `eth0`.  Those sysctls are used to prevent the existence of hidden address (VIP assigned to `lo`) from being exposed to other hosts via ARP on `eth0`.

Comment: Looks like that's true.  I found a great reference page that explains the two settings in more detail: http://blog.cj2s.de/archives/29-Preventing-ARP-flux-on-Linux.html

Comment: This is a better reference: http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Using_arp_announce/arp_ignore_to_disable_ARP